# Split lxml etree into multiple etree objects Python

Tags: python, lxml

Is there a function to split an etree object set of child elements into multiple etree objects by index?
For example, if my root node had say 400 children each with descendants, could I get 4 etree objects from each second of the file?

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('FileName.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

firstquarter = root.getchildren()   #function to get 0-100 of the child nodes
secondquarter = root.getchildren()  #function to get 101-200 of the child nodes
thirdquarter = root.getchildren()   #function to get 201-300 of the child nodes
fourthquarter = root.getchildren()  #function to get 301-400 of the child nodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it simply with something like

```
firstquarter = root.getchildren()[0:100]
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll give it a go in the morning. If it works you get the checkmark!

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but may be useable non the less.